# ffmpeg audio encoder frame size

Tags: audio, encoding, ffmpeg

I need to convert audio data from AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S16LE to AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_ALAW and I am using [this](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/encode_audio_8c-example.html#a36) code as an example. The example code does essentially this (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
const AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MP2);
AVCodecContext* c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
c->bit_rate       = 64000;
c->sample_fmt     = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;
c->sample_rate    = select_sample_rate(codec);
c->channel_layout = select_channel_layout(codec);
c->channels       = av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(c->channel_layout);
avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL);
AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
frame->nb_samples     = c->frame_size;
frame->format         = c->sample_fmt;
frame->channel_layout = c->channel_layout;
```

The example code subsequently uses `c->frame_size` in a for loop.

My code is similar to the above with the following differences:

```
const AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_ALAW);
c->sample_rate    = 8000;
c->channel_layout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO;
c->channels       = 1;
```

After calling  `avcodec_open2`, `c->frame_size` is zero. The example code never sets the frame size so I assume that it expects either `avcodec_alloc_context3` or `avcodec_open2` to set it. Is this a correct assumption? Is the setting of the frame size based on the codec being used? If I have to set the frame size explicitly, is there a recommended size?

EDIT:

Based on @the-kamilz answer it appears that the example code is not robust. The example assumes that `c->frame_size` will be set but that appears to be dependent on the codec. In my case, `codec->capabilities` was in fact set to `AV_CODEC_CAP_VARIABLE_FRAME_SIZE`. So I modified my code to check `c->frame_size` and use it only if it is not zero. If it is zero, I just picked an arbitrary one second worth of data for `frame->nb_samples`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the FFmpeg documentation it is mentioned as:

> **int AVCodecContext::frame_size**
>
> Number of samples per channel in an audio frame.
>
> `encoding`: set by libavcodec in `avcodec_open2()`. Each submitted frame except the last must contain exactly `frame_size` samples per channel.
>   May be `0` when the codec has `AV_CODEC_CAP_VARIABLE_FRAME_SIZE` set, then
>   the frame size is not restricted.
>   `decoding`: may be set by some decoders to indicate constant frame size

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you don't control the frame size explicitly, it is set by the encoder depending on the codecs provided at initialization (opening) time

once `avcodec_open2()` is successful, you can retrieve the frame's buffer size with [av_samples_get_buffer_size()](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__sampfmts.html#gaa7368bc4e3a366b688e81938ed55eb06)

Comment: And what value do I pass to `av_samples_get_buffer_size()` for `nb_samples`?

Comment: :) OK sorry my bad